# Using awk to calculate word counts in multiple columns

Tags: linux, unix, awk

## Input file (tab separated)

```
1 . Hello World . 51.4 . This is a text . 200
2 . Another line . 16.4 . Some more words . 600
```

## Output desired (tab separated)

```
Hello World . 2 . This is a text . 4 
Another line . 2 . Some more words . 3
```

The output is columns 2 and 4, and their word counts

I've gotten to

```
awk '{print $2, "\t", NF}' > output.tsv
```

but don't know how to do this for multiple columns in a single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
           {print $2,split($2,x," +"),$4,split($4,x," +")}' file

Hello World     2   This is a text  4
Another line    2   Some more words 3
```